# What does it mean "Failed to load COM32 file"

Tags: pxe, syslinux

I have the following pxelinux config:

```
DEFAULT vesamenu.c32
PROMPT 0

MENU TITLE In The Moon Network

LABEL install1404server
MENU LABEL Install Ubuntu 14.04.1 Server AMD64
include ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/menu.cfg
default ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32
```

All mentioned files are accessed by tftpd.

When I do network boot, my menu appears. When I select the (single) item, the following error message appears:

```
Failed to load COM32 file ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32
```

Loading is occurred on virtual machine.

What is happening which causes this error message?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this, I had to redownload everything under my 'ubuntu-installer' directory. I don't know if they were supposed to be binary and they were ascii or the other way around or if they were simply corrupt. As soon as I put the freshly downloaded files in my tftp directory, pxe boot worked great.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means the `PXELINUX` bootloader is attempting a TFTP download of file `ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32` and failing.

Could be a file permissions issue, or a file corruption issue as suggested by @clickwir.

If the TFTP server software is set to log all requests, checking its log might be helpful: if the TFTP server has logged an error, it's probably a file permissions issue on the server, but if the TFTP download has been successful, the file was probably corrupt on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This error message can also be displayed when a com32 module is not compatible with the version of PXELINUX you are using.

Debian and probably also Ubuntu includes a netboot tarball as part of the installer with each release for netbooting. If you don't use the version of PXELINUX provided in the tarball you can have incompatibility issues as I have found.

The server sends the correct file and the checksums all match but the error is as in the original question. Using the distribution supplied pxelinux.0 corrects the issue.

See: https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Common_Problems#Modules